# Build list of data based on criteria with mutliple results - Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have a tab with a list of files in multiple folders, with the folder name too.  On another tab I have a list of notification numbers, eg. 12345678.  Multiple files (lines) will have the notification number with the file name:

```
Filename:
    -026D0003 12523032 IWS.pdf
    -026D0003 12523032 TQ 2016-INT-013.pdf
    -026D0003 13074692 THO.pdf
    -026D0003 13104853 REV 01 WSE.pdf
    -026D0003 13104853 WSE.pdf
    -026D0003 13169779 NDT Request.pdf
```

To the right of these filenames is the folder they're in.  The filename above is made up of item number, notification number, description.

So, on the second tab, I have the notification number.  Using VLOOKUP with a wildcard, I could pull up the first instance where the notification number occurs in the filename, returning the folder name.  Unfortunately, this only shows the first instance of the notification number, not all of them.

```
Notification number list:
    -12523032
    -13074692 
    -13169779
```

Is there a way I can build a list of the folders (second column to filename) for each occurrence of the notification numbers, not just the first one?

Comment: Would it possible to use a pivot table? You could use the filter to search for the numbers needed.

Comment: Can you use Excel's Power Query? It makes this sort of thing pretty simple.

Comment: I have a list of notification numbers and need to build a list of filenames with those numbers.  Vlookup only returns the first instance but I need every instance.
So, filenames can be:
026D0001 12345678 ABC.pdf
026D0001 12345678 DEF.pdf
081C0001 87654321 GHI.doc
081C0001 87654321 JKL.pdf
081C0001 87654321 MNO.jpg
081C0001 11223344 PQY.dwg

I need to go down a list of notification numbers and return the filenames with those numbers so I can build an import sheet to attach the files to entries in our software.

Comment: I've never used Power Query and wouldn't be able to install it at work, but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I didn't think of a pivot table.  Would I be able to do that on a notification number within other text (the filename)?